# How I can work with Amazon's Dynamodb Local in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Amazon offers a [local simulator for their Dynamodb product](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/09/12/amazon-dynamodb-local/) but the [examples are only in PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.html).

These examples mention passing the parameter "base_url" to specify that you're using a local Dynamodb, but that returns this error in Node:

```
{ [UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.]
  message: 'The security token included in the request is invalid.',
  code: 'UnrecognizedClientException',
  name: 'UnrecognizedClientException',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false }
```

How do I get Dynamodb_local working in Node?

Comment: Did you createa table using aws-sdk and this dynamo local?

Answer (score 57):

You should follow this [blog post](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development.html) to setup your DynamoDB Local, an then you can simply use this code:

```
var AWS= require('aws-sdk'),
dyn= new AWS.DynamoDB({ endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:8000') });

dyn.listTables(function (err, data)
{
   console.log('listTables',err,data);
});
```

Comment: You may also be interested in https://github.com/aaaristo/dyngodb, in which case you can simply issue: _dyngodb --local_

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like the PHP SDK uses "base_url" where the Node SDK uses "endpoint".

Comment: For others new to AWS like I was, after line 1 I needed to add `AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: "myKeyId", secretAccessKey: "secretKey", region: "us-east-1" });`

Comment: I suggest you to use the environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_REGION) instead of using AWS.config.update. http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/nodejs/

Comment: I can't create a table with this code. `dyn.createTable({
  TableName: 'myTbl',
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    { AttributeName: 'aaa', AttributeType: 'S' },
  ],
  KeySchema:[
    { AttributeName: 'aaa', KeyType: 'HASH' }
  ]
}, function() { 
    dyn.listTables(function(err, data) {
      console.log(data)
  });
});`

Comment: please look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224061/how-to-query-local-dynamodb-using-dynamoose

Answer (score 9):

For Node please do as below:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const AWSaccessKeyId = 'not-important';
const AWSsecretAccessKey = 'not-important';      
const AWSregion = 'local';
const AWSendpoint = 'http://localhost:8000' // This is required
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: AWSaccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: AWSsecretAccessKey,  
    region: AWSregion,
    endpoint: AWSendpoint
});
```

Ensure that DynamodDB is running on port 8000.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it, same code works local or inside AWS.

Simply leverage existence of env var `DYNAMO_LOCAL_ENDPT="http://localhost:8000"`

```js
import { DynamoDB, Endpoint } from 'aws-sdk';

const ddb = new DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

if (process.env['DYNAMO_LOCAL_ENDPT']) {
  ddb.endpoint = new Endpoint(process.env['DYNAMO_LOCAL_ENDPT']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Nodejs with Typescript, this code **might not work**. Because there is no property call endpoint.

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: AWSaccessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: AWSsecretAccessKey,  
  region: AWSregion,
  endpoint: AWSendpoint 
});
```

You can use either,

```
dyn= new AWS.DynamoDB({ endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:8000') });
```

or

```
AWS.config.dynamodb = {
  endpoint: new Endpoint('http://localhost:8000'),
  region: 'us-east-1'
}
```